# How can I let authenticated users rebuild caches?

Tags: 8, caching

Is there a way for authenticated users to clear the cache without giving them the administer site permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's what I created [Rebuild Cache Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/rebuild_cache_access) for.

> This module provides a new permission: `rebuild cache access`. Every
>   role with this permission set will have a nice and big "Rebuild Cache"
>   admin toolbar button. Clicking this button simply fires
>   `drupal_flush_all_caches()`. That's all.